# Buildozer build fails at NDK build giving SDL_JAVA_PACKAGE_PATH error

Tags: android-ndk, kivy, buildozer

Buildozer (0.34) fails with this error when set up using Kivy's VM (2.0). I was able to replicate it in an unrelated environment (no VM) in Ubuntu 16.04 and the same spec file.

**Log output:**

> [INFO]:    STDOUT:
>         /build/app-name/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2_gradle-python2/jni/sdl/Android.mk:8:
>   *** Please define SDL_JAVA_PACKAGE_PATH to the path of your Java package with dots replaced with underscores, for example
>   "com_example_SanAngeles".  Stop.

This happened right after it switched to running the NDK build:

**Log output:**

> ```
>   RAN: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build V=1
> ```

Does anyone have insight into why this error would appear exactly the same way in both the VM and when I set up the environment on my own? Is it Java-related somehow? I will elaborate with more detail, but I'm not sure what would be the most helpful. I can't find references to this error elsewhere, and I would appreciate any clues at all. This is my first question on SO, but this community has really helped me learn. Thank you.

Comment: I should have posted the entire log output because this error was related to the ndk-build step, and what I chose to post doesn't show it. The only way to continue was to delete all buildozer folders, uninstall buildozer and kivy, then start again with a new buildozer spec file. I will leave this question open in case someone else has a better insight, but the workaround was basically to reinstall everything.